# Replace comma between square brackets using PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text file; within the file I have some square brackets that may include a comma. I want to replace/remove this comma.
Say the text =

> ##logissue type=warning;Column 'Employee'[Address, Post]. Do not use floating point data types"

I want:

> ##logissue type=warning;Column 'Employee'[Address Post]. Do not use floating point data types"

I am using this PowerShell script, but this one is replacing everything within the square brackets.

```
$string -replace '\[.*\]', ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell supports infinite quantifiers in a lookbehind assertion and you can assert `[` to the left and `]` to the right while matching a comma.

```
(?<=\[[^][]*),(?=[^][]*])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\[[^][]*)` Assert `[` to the left matching any char except `[` and `]` in between
- `,` Match the comma
- `(?=[^][]*])` Assert `]` to the right matching any char except `[` and `]` in between

[.NET regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhi0qi/1)

```
$string = "##logissue type=warning;Column 'Employee'[Address, Post]. Do not use floating point data types"
$string -replace '(?<=\[[^][]*),(?=[^][]*])', ''
```

Output

```
##logissue type=warning;Column 'Employee'[Address Post]. Do not use floating point data types
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture everything inside the square brackets and do the [replacement with the help of a script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#replacement-with-a-script-block).

Within the script block, you can use the `$_` automatic variable to access the input text being replaced. Also note that this variable class type is `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`. Hence you need to use [`.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-capture-value) to gets the captured substring.

```
$string -replace "\[(.*?)\]", { $_.Value.replace(",", "") }
```

Please note that this is available in PowerShell 6 and later.

For older versions, you can use the [`Replace` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) from
the [.NET `regex` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0).

```
[regex]::Replace($string, "\[(.*?)\]", { $args[0].Value.replace(',', "") })
```

Comment: I am using 5.1v